# Are there international treaties preventing states from taxing property transfers out of it?

Tags: international, tax-law, treaty

With the goal of discouraging companies and high net worth individuals from leaving the country to save taxes by taxing wealth leaving the country by a multiple of the taxes due per year if they stayed.

With "state" I mean a sovereign state which nationally can do whatever it wants, I'm only asking about international treaties/laws.

Purely hypothetical question, sorry if this shows a lack of basic understanding on my part. To me it seems like that would be qualitatively similar to the transaction tax some people have been proposing.

Comment: What people? What country?

Comment: @Nij Well, if you *have* to be specific, Switzerland. But really I'm interested in a global picture. If there are such treaties, there are probably many member countries. If there aren't many member countries in such a treaty, then the treaty is less relevant because that would (usually) also mean there is less pressure to stay in the treaty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of any such treaties (although some free trade treaties such as the treaties forming the EU may have that effect among members nations). Limitations on removing assets from a country aren't that uncommon. Many countries have them and more have had them historically. There is a small sub-field within economics that examines the effect of such restrictions.

Comment: What is that subfield called?